# SSH2 for PHP7 MacOS?

Tags: macos, ssh, pecl, php-7.1, ssh2-sftp

When trying to use

```
ssh2_sftp($this->con);
```

PHP 7.1.7 thinks Im looking for a function in the class. After some reading, I found that SSH2 needs to be installed from PECL 
( http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php )

When I went to do that, I got the following error:

```
pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.1.7
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to run on MacOs 10.13.3 (17D47) with PHP 7.1.7?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24):

I finally found a solution on MacOS Mohave. I have PHP 7.3 installed by Homebrew:

```
brew install php
brew install libssh2
```

Install development version of ssh2 pecl extension from the latest sources:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-ssh2.git
cd pecl-networking-ssh2
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Enable extension in `php.ini`. You can use TextEdit:

```
open -e /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
```

Add `extension="ssh2.so"` to the beginning of the file and save.

Test the result:

```
php -i | grep 'libssh2 version'
```

You should see

```
libssh2 version => 1.10.0
```

**-- EDIT for Apple silicon (M1)**

Homebrew uses different path on Apple silicon machines and ./configure command fails with error: "checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found". I resolved this with setting custom path:

```
./configure --with-ssh2=/opt/homebrew/opt/libssh2
```

Comment: This is the one that works for me! Thank you so much for posting this answer.

Comment: +1 on this. It'll install ssh2 version 1.8.0. Thanks! You just unblocked our company's php7.3 update. :)

Comment: the new location for ssh2 (march 2022) is https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-ssh2.git

Comment: After successful ssh2 install I still have Error 32759. Unable to find the socket transport "ssh2.sftp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: For me (PHP 7.4 & macOS Ventura M1) just `pecl install ssh2` and specifying _/opt/homebrew/opt/libssh2_ when asked, did the trick. I already had _libssh2_ installed with brew.

Answer (score 13):

I managed to install php-ssh2 on MacOS High Sierra.

First I had to install `libssh2`, in order for PECL to compile the extension.

I used brew, however most likely libssh2 is available from mac ports also.

```
brew install libssh2
```

and then

```
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

I have the Xcode command line tools (already) installed - which I assume was needed to compile the extension.

Comment: I tried this on a Mac running Mojave,  and I got this error on "pecl install ssh2-1.1.2":  No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/ssh2"
install failed

Comment: I tried on Mohave. Instalelled libssh2 1.9.0 without any problems. Than pecl installation failed with 17 warnings and 3 errors. It looks like incompatibility between libssh2 and pecl extension.

Comment: any luck so far?

Comment: worked for me. libssh2 was pulled in v1.9.0.1 from brew but pecl install only worked with ssh2-1.2

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Catalina (10.15.2). Slight modification - I did `pecl install ssh2-1.2`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

You can see available versions for ssh2 [HERE](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

For those using alpine linux, make sure to add libssh2-dev first:

```
apk --update add libssh2-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Big Sur:

```
brew install libssh2
pecl install ssh2-1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Big Sur and with MacPorts and MAMP Pro:

```
sudo port install libssh2
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://git.php.net/repository/pecl/networking/ssh2.git
cd ssh2
```

Then use an editor and edit ~/Downloads/ssh2/config.m4 around line 7 and change the search paths "/usr/local /usr" to "/usr/local /usr /opt/local" like this

```
if test "$PHP_SSH2" != "no"; then
    SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr /opt/local"
```

save and go on:

```
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Then follow the [steps in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886490/ssh2-for-php7-macos#answer-57280595) and regarding your PHP version…